# Javascript asynchronous function: callback not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http

I am trying to return a result from an asynchronous function in Javascript.

I have seen this question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), and I am trying to implement the callback solution, but something is wrong.

This is my code:

```
function getLocation(callback){
    var lat;
    var long;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
                {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                }, function()
                {
                    console.log('Please enable geolocation in your browser.');
                });
    } else {
        alert('It seems like geolocation is not enabled in your browser.');
    }
var res = {
        "lat": lat,
        "long": long
};
callback(res);
}

function getEventNearYou(){
    var list = [];
    getLocation(function(obj){
        var lat = obj.lat;
        var long = obj.long;
        $.ajax({
                url : 'http://www.skiddle.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=myapikey' + '&latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + long + '&radius=800&eventcode=LIVE&order=distance&description=1',
                type : "GET",
                async : false,
                success : function(response) {
                        $(response).find("results").each(function() {
                        var el = $(this);
                        var obj = {
                                    "eventname" : el.find("eventname").text(),
                                    "imageurl" : el.find("imageurl").text(),
                                  }
                        list.push(obj);
                        });
                        } 
                });
        return list;
    });
}
```

Basically, I want to find my current location, and create a HTTP get request to www.skiddle.com to retrieve events near that location.

This is how I call the function:

```
var x = getEventNearYou();
```

but I seem to have made a mistake, since I am getting the bad request error (`lat` and `long` are undefined).

Comment: What is `obj` that is parameter to `getLocation`? What is purpose of redefining `obj` within `success`?

Comment: seems like `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` have callback function. So before you get that callback run  `callback(res);` will executed.
That is why you will not get `lat` and `long` values.

Comment: @dwij What would be the recommended way to deal with this?

Comment: try `callback(res);` inside `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` success function. Also you need to push the `res` variable assignment to that success function

Comment: @dwij That helped with the request, which is now fine, but the list of objects I want to return from the `getEventNearYou()` is still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using callbacks in a way that undermines their usefulness. You're still writing your code in a synchronous style. You should continue to reference: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/5743988)

In the mean time, I'll restructure your code to show how it's done.

1. As a rule of thumb, if any of the code inside a function uses callbacks, that outer function also needs to accept a callback as a parameter.
2. If a variable is given a value inside a callback function, it won't be defined outside of the callback function (because asynchronous code always runs *after* synchronous code).
3. Don't use `async: false`

```
function getLocation(callback){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            var res = { "lat": lat, "long": long }; 
            callback(res);
        }, function() {
            console.log('Please enable geolocation in your browser.');
        });
    } else {
        alert('It seems like geolocation is not enabled in your browser.');
    }
}

function getEventNearYou(callback) {
    getLocation(function(pos){
        var lat = pos.lat;
        var long = pos.long;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.skiddle.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=myapikey' + '&latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + long + '&radius=800&eventcode=LIVE&order=distance&description=1',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                var list = [];
                $(response).find("results").each(function() {
                    var el = $(this);
                    var obj = {
                        "eventname": el.find("eventname").text(),
                        "imageurl" : el.find("imageurl").text(),
                    };
                    list.push(obj);
                });
                callback(list);
            } 
        });
    });
}
```

Then call `getEventNearYou` using a callback function:

```
getEventNearYou(function (events) {
    // code which relies on `events` can be called from here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a bit more explanation to 4castle's excellent answer. In the code you wrote, when your `getLocation()` function is called in Javascript, this is what will happen:

1. `var lat` and `var long` are instantiated with values of `undefined`.
2. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is called, which takes a long time to complete.
3. **In the meantime, Javascript looks for something else to do** and moves to the next lines in your function.
4. The `res` object is instantiated with the current **undefined** values of `lat` and `long`. That is, `res` is: `{ "lat": undefined, "long": undefined }`
5. The `callback` function is called on `res`. This means `callback` is called with undefined values for `lat` and `long`.
6. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` finally finishes what it was doing and assigns values to `lat` and `long`, but by now it is too late because your callback function was already called on the undefined values.

In 4castle's revised code, steps 4-5 are put inside an anonymous callback function to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, which means these lines won't be executed until `getCurrentPosition()` is finished getting the position.